# redirect from one webpage to two other webpages

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

Actually I am using API to send SMS from a webpage from my site.
The SMS gateway site just gives the feedback of delivery, doesn't return to my website.
After sending SMS, I need to send emails & update database.
I know JavaScript & php.

I don't want to depend on SMS gateways redirection, is there a way to go to their webpage & return back without their involvement?

Comment: This would only be possible with the use of an iframe. Or Ajax if allowed. Like @BriceFavre and Eugen said cURL is also an option if available.

Comment: We need more information but i think you can developp something with CURL.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php

Comment: http://BULKSMS.POWEREDSMS.COM/send.php?usr=rajdeeps&pwd=pass123&ph=xxxxxxxxxxx&sndr=textid&text=hi
this is the URL I need to use to send SMS. how could I do that, please explain with code.

Comment: With due respect, the comments and answers here should be enough to get you pointed in the right direction.  You really should take a look at the documentation links provided and the API documentation for the SMS gateway.  If you have problems with specific portions of your code after doing so, I'm sure that we'd be glad to help.  However, asking "please explain with code" gives the impression that you are expecting us to write it for you and are unwilling to work towards doing so yourself.  That may not be the best way to encourage more help going forward.

Comment: i'm not able to understand cURL, its something about opening a file, how can I get help with it??

Comment: I'd suggest that you try googling for something similar to "PHP cURL tutorial" and checking out the results.  For example, here are two that may help get you started:  http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-tutorial-and-example/  and   http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the API from your server using cURL and keep the client experience completly under your control - this way you not only can redirect, AJAX or whatever as much as you want, you can also doge some low-flying bullets with clients abusing your pages.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I assume that you are transferring control to the SMS gateway site by redirecting the browser to it, then  no.  Once the browser leaves your site and loads the gateway site, you no longer have the ability to run any code.

If you are, instead, invoking the SMS gateway API via server or client side code, then yes.  Once the HTTP request that invokes the API is complete, you will be able to perform a redirect as you normally would.

Comment: Thank you jesse, could you emphasize on the second part you suggested?

Comment: Rather than redirecting to the SMS gateway, you would load a page of your own which collects the same form fields.  When that form is submitted, you would use a call to cURL (or your preferred method of reading from an HTTP endpoint) to pass those form fields to the SMS gateway.  Then, you would inspect the response that the gateway sent you.  If you find the success value that you're looking for, you can perform your redirect.  One thing to note here - if this isn't a documented API by the gateway, it is brittle and could break if the gateway updates their HTML code.  Be wary.

Comment: http://bulksms.poweredsms.com/send.php?usr=rajdeeps&pwd=pass123&ph=xxxxxxxxxxx&sndr=textid&text=hi
  This is the link to send sms, i have the details in database and session variables that i can manage to pass, after executing this link, I want to stay on same page or one of my other webpage. could you give the code for this, i'm unaware of cURL?

Comment: At a glance, it appears that the gateway is exposing a simple API using GET-based variables.  It should work nicely for you as described above.  To get started, take a peek at the PHP manual page for cURL (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and a simple example (http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)